# Generating triplets of random number not aligned

Tags: matlab, math

given a square matrix of size N

e.g. for a 3x3 case  A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]

I want to generate 3 random triplets (with the numbers inside the matrix) such that the points are not aligned. Therefore triplets that are not rows and column of the matrix.

Anyone knows a smoth ad agile way to code this? Thank you all

Comment: Do you mean you want no two values to be in the same row or column, or (less strictly) that not all the values are in the same row or column? Need all three values in the triplet be distinct? And do you want to return all such triplets with uniform probability, or is that not necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
r=[];
while size(r,1)<3
    idx = randi(numel(A),[1,3]); %random indices
    [i,j]=ind2sub(size(A),idx);  %subs
    if ~(all(i(1)==i)||all(j(1)==j)) %not all from same row or column
        r(end+1,:)=A(idx); %add to result
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you @Gelliant